# Input range ios mobile drag on track

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, input, safari

Whn I add input range on mobile ios (both chrome and safari) range cannot be dragged unless you tap on the actual thumb, while on android wherever you tap you can still drag the input.

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="11">
```

Is there a fix for this, with css or javascript?